# How to Programmatically Add Views to ViewContainer?

Tags: java, android

When I override the `public Object instantiateItem` function of `MainAdapter extends PagerAdapter` , at line `container.addView(`,it crash down. I receive the following log

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout(ViewGroup.java:3909)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout(ViewGroup.java:3890)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:1302)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3744)
        at com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager.addView(JazzyViewPager.java:127)
        at com.ycg.bottommenuslidegradientswipe.MainActivity$MainAdapter.instantiateItem(MainActivity.java:260)
```

My code of the `instanstiateItem` function is shown below. Class `TaskCompletedView` extends `View`

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    TasksCompletedView mTasksView = (TasksCompletedView) findViewById(R.id.tasks_view);
    container.addView(mTasksView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    jazzyPager.setObjectForPosition(mTasksView,position);

    new Thread(new ProgressRunable()).start();
    return mTasksView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happen because you set null variable.
mTasksView == null;
You need put not null view, example:

```
container.addView(new ImageView(context), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: I don't know where to update my code. I used the line   `findViewById(R.id.tasks_view);` to initialize mTaskView.  The `mTaskView`, Class `TaskCompletedView` extends `View`.

Comment: @PeterZhu So,  findViewById return null because view with that id not found. Please satisfied about view correct initialization.